# Most efficient way in java to continually read small files into an object

Tags: java, performance, kotlin, nio

tl/dr:  I need to keep some values in my app up to date with the values in ~10 small files, but I'm worried reading the value over and over will have a lot of GC overhead. Do I create a bunch of unbuffered file readers and poll them, or is there any way to "map" the values in a file into a java Double that I can re-run a moment later when the value (maybe) changed?

Long version: I've got some physical sensors (Gyroscope, tachometer) which [ev3dev](http://docs.ev3dev.org/projects/lego-linux-drivers/en/ev3dev-stretch/sensors.html#sysfs) helpfully exposes their current values as small files in a virtual filesystem.  Like one file called "/sys/bus/lego/drivers/ev3-analog-sensor/angle" that contains `56.26712`

Or the next moment it contains `58.9834`

And I'd like a value in my app to keep as close in sync with that file as possible.  I could have your standard loop containing `MappedByteBuffer buffer = inChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, inChannel.size());` (from [here](https://howtodoinjava.com/java7/nio/3-ways-to-read-files-using-java-nio/)) but that seems like a lot of allocation overhead if it put it in a fast loop.

Maybe something with a Scanner, or 
`FileChannel inChannel = aFile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
        while(inChannel.read(buffer) > 0)...`

I haven't found a magic function of `KeepInSyncWithFile(myFloatArray, File("./angle", MODE.FILE_TO_VALUE, 10, TimeUnits.MS)`

Java 8+

Comment: Does the file have a constant size?

Comment: @Benjamin, if I understand, do you want to read small files very efficiently ? Is this your question ?

Comment: not very sure, but are you looking for a `Watcher` of files been changed?

Comment: @Eugene I bet `Watcher` is useless here, since this is not a real file on a disk, but rather a pseudofile, an interface to the device driver. So, there is no event like "the file has changed". The values "appear" when the file is read.

Comment: Watcher didn't seem to trigger.

Comment: @apangin good point and a very good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Singe you are talking about pseudofiles on `/sys` virtual filesystem, it's unlikely that the standard [`WatchService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/WatchService.html) will work for them. In order to get updated values, you need to read these files.

The good news is that you can keep reading in a garbage-free manner, i.e. with no allocation at all. Open the file and allocate the buffer just once, and every time you want to read a value, seek to the beginning of the file and read to an existing preallocated buffer.

Here is the code:

```
public class DeviceReader implements Closeable {
    private final RandomAccessFile file;
    private final byte[] buf = new byte[512];

    public DeviceReader(String fileName) throws IOException {
        this.file = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "r");
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        file.close();
    }

    public synchronized double readDouble() throws IOException {
        file.seek(0);
        int length = file.read(buf);
        if (length <= 0) {
            throw new EOFException();
        }

        int sign = 1;
        long exp = 0;
        long value = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            byte ch = buf[i];
            if (ch == '-') {
                sign = -1;
            } else if (ch == '.') {
                exp = 1;
            } else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') {
                value = (value * 10) + (ch - '0');
                exp *= 10;
            } else if (ch < ' ') {
                break;
            }
        }

        return (double) (sign * value) / Math.max(1, exp);
    }
}
```

Note that I manually parse a floating point number from a `byte[]` buffer. It would be much easier to call `Double.parseDouble`, but in this case you'd have to convert a `byte[]` to a `String`, and the algorithm will no longer be allocation free.

Comment: That is really slick. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

I can't vouch for this but, [File Observer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/FileObserver) might be worth looking into. You can cache the latest values in your app and observe the file via `FileObserver` to find if any modify event occurs. I personally don't have any experience working with it, so I can't say for sure as to whether it would work with system files. But if it does, then it's a better solution when compared to just repeatedly looking up the file in a loop.